# How can I make this MiniZinc output statement compile?

Tags: output, minizinc

How do I revise this to compile in MiniZinc:

```
output [[show (P[j,p]) ++ "\n" | p in 1 .. 4] | j in 1 .. 4];
```

I tried several ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do. Here are some different approaches that will write P as a matrix. The first one write the matrix as lists ([...]), the second one just outputs the values.

```
output [  
   show([P[j,p] | p in 1 .. 4]) ++ "\n"
   | j in 1 .. 4
];


output [  
   if p = 1 then "\n" else " " endif ++
     show(P[j,p])
    | j in 1 .. 4, p in 1 .. 4
];
```

Update: In MiniZinc 2.0 (at least in a fairly recent Git version), there is now a show2d predicate:

```
 output [ show2d(P)];
```

Comment: I was able to adapt that to my larger code and after a few tries finally got it to work - thanks!